# Which scenario is better for managing hibernate relationship for User and UserPreference?

Tags: java, hibernate

I would like too see some opinions of experienced hibernate developers, so I can elaborate my own.

I have the following scenario:

- User has many UserPreference
- UserPreference has one User
- UserPreference has one Preference
- Preference has many UserPreference

I can think of two ways of doing this (omitted some fields to make it clear):

1) UserPreference on the User side:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

     private String username;

     private String password;

     @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
     private Set<UserPreference> userPreferences;
}

@Entity
public class UserPreference implements Serializable {

     private String value;

     @ManyToOne
     private Preference preference;
}

@Entity
public class Preference implements Serializable {

     private String preferenceName;

     private String defaultValue;
 }
```

2) User on the UserPreference side:

```
@Entity
public class UserPreference implements Serializable {

     private String value;

     @ManyToOne
     private User user;

     @ManyToOne
     private Preference preference;
}


@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {

     private String username;

     private String password;
}


@Entity
public class Preference implements Serializable {

     private String preferenceName;

     private String defaultValue;
}
```

In your opinion, which one do you think is better? Why? Feel free to show your own method, if is different from mine. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first is better, simply because you can do

`userPreferences.contains(aPreference);`

to check for given Preferences existance(provided hashCode and equals are ok).

Answer (score 1):

As you are new to hibernate Don't create mess with number of Beans .

Use only User and Preference beans .

So that user may have number preferences and preference may have number of Users.

use many to many on both sides .

Comment: I understand your point, but I really need those beans. It's a requirement in my project.

Comment: So  go for first one ..cheers .if possible merge the Preference and UserPreference fields . :)